# how to make embedded web page scrollable in android webview?

Tags: object, webview, scroll

android Webview loads a remote web page that embeds another web page as object data value.
I want to make the page open in object scroll.
But no suggestion so far on net could help me

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: perhaps i made several unnecessary changes in layout and activity like putting webview in viewscroll and changing webview height and width

Comment: i dynamically load pages in object through js